# AutoCompleteTextView's dropdownwindow has a blank area

Tags: android-layout

When I'm using `AutoCompleteTextView`, I provide a `ArrayAdapter` to `AutoCompleteTextView` using `setAdapter()` API - the dropdown Windows shows normal

But when I scroll the dropdown Windows, it shows a blank area at the bottom of the dropdown Windows which I don't want to show. How to remove the blank area.

Comment: can you provide screenshot pls?

Comment: sorry ! I  hava no authority to upload image.|     |